# Close live agent chat window when the user click on end chat

Tags: liveagent, chat

Is it possible to close the chat window when the user click on "end chat"?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour], and read [ask]. Generally speaking, questions that can be answered with a simple yes/no aren't a good fit for this site. Showing the community what research you've done, and what you've tried to do prior to asking a question usually goes a long way to getting a positive response on this site. Probably the biggest key to success here on this site is to provide plenty of details, because more details usually means the other contributors have to assume fewer things (which leads to more more accurate and tailored answers). Just some things to be aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not override end chat button behavior on standard chat window, so we can not do that.

However, a way to get it by creating your own chat window, of course, not a practical option but you can give a try: https://rajvakati.com/2017/11/02/salesforce-custom-chat-window/